# Can't find a garden hose that fits

Tags: valve, hose, gardening

Just moved into a new house and the spigot the in backyard is too big for the hose I bought. Is there an adapter or a special hose that can fit this? [image: Front photo of the faucet][image: side photo of the faucet]

Comment: Thank you so much for time and information. Here is a side picture.

Comment: Thanks for the great additional picture. It is really awesome when someone takes the time to post a well lighted and focused picture. I would say from what I see here that part on the end of your faucet should be able to be removed. If the set screw (rusty part on top) is still engaging the threads of the faucet nib it may require some more work than just unscrewing the remaining part of the adapter. If you do apply a pair of long handled pliers or a pipe wrench to the adapter do try to also hold onto the valve assembly as well to counter the applied (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) force so that the piping going into the wall or the valve itself does not sustain damage or become unthreaded from the pipe. Best place to support the valve would be at the hex shaped part.

Comment: Ok i will try to unscrew it. Thanks so much! Your explanation was awesome! 

Comment: I did it! Im soo happy! Hip Hip Hooray !! 

Comment: It's important to note that there is a setscrew in the side of the fitting, barely visible at the top.  This setscrew must be loosened or removed before you will be able to unscrew the fitting.

Comment: It might be worth considering keeping both the front view and side view pictures

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is not a standard garden hose fitting. Instead it looks to be part of a anti-siphon adapter where the other part was unscrewed to reveal the inner section of the unit. The regular hose thread coupling would have been on the down stream part of the missing part.

It will be unlikely that you can find just half of a anti-siphon adapter that would screw on there unless you got rather lucky and happened to find an identical new one and were able to cannibalize it for the missing part.

Also it looks to me that the way that remaining part is corroded that you would not want to keep that part anyway and would likely want to replace with a new one where the anti-siphon feature would actually work correctly.

It would be great if you could provide an additional picture from the side of the valve. Some additional advice may be possible to offer after seeing that. The reason I say that is because I see a knurled portion of the remaining part that looks a lot like a anti-siphon adapter shown in this picture.

[image]

This type of adapter is designed to thread onto the regular hose nib of the valve and then the hose attaches to the hose threads shown on the left side of the picture. You may be able to remove the part of the adapter that is still remaining threaded onto your valve.

Do be aware though that some valves are designed with the anti-siphon feature integrated right into the fundamental part of the valve. A side picture would help to identify the situation. I suspect that in your case it is not integrated because I see from your picture there is a rusty hole where the locking set screw from the original part must have been attached. Hopefully the valve itself is a brass valve. An iron one may have rusted so bad that it may be very difficult to remove/replace the defunct anti-siphon adapter.

In case you are wondering...the set screw on the pictured adapter is used to secure the anti-siphon adapter onto the valve threads and keep it from turning when attaching or removing the hose from the opposite end of the adapter.

Comment: I've never heard of such an item - could you please extend the answer to include its function?   Is it to stop water being "stolen" like a car petrol/gasoline anti-siphon?  Or is it to stop the water retreating back into the tap and sucking air into the plumbing system?

Comment: @Criggie I think the more common (or at least more technical name) is a backflow preventer. It's to stop water in the attached hose (which may not be potable) from being sucked back into the potable water system.

Comment: What dero said.  It prevents the induction from running indoor faucets from pulling water into the system. Without it, if your outdoor spigot is on, you may be pulling hose water into your drinking water. Today, they're usually built-in to anti-freeze spigots.