# garden spigot adaptor

Tags: plumbing, spigot

My house is ~20yrs old.

We're on well-water, so the outdoor water is pretty skanky (sulphur, iron, iron-eating bacteria).

Last October, in trying to disconnect the hose from the spigot, I ended up removing some sort of adapter-piece that had been "part of" the spigot.

(See photos.) https://photos.app.goo.gl/StogbWib8bacVUMp6

I bought something to "solve" the problem, and like an idiot threw away the gross end of hose.

Now I realize I can't figure out what size adaptor I need. I've seen some posts refer to "vacuum breakers", but this seems to be an anti-syphon spigot, which uses a different piece.

None of the pieces at the local hardware stores are big enough (see photos for those).

What can I do?

Is this question redundant to: [Can't find a garden hose that fits](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110913/cant-find-a-garden-hose-that-fits) ?

Answer (score 3):

Your hose faucet came equipped with a vacuum-breaker (call it an "anti-siphon" if you will, it serves the same purpose: preventing dirty water from your garden from getting sucked up into the fresh water supply if there were a drop in line pressure). This type of spigot was likely required by code when your house was built.

The thread that the valve manufacturer uses to attach *their* anti-siphon device **is not standard**. In fact, it is deliberately not standard because "they" don't want end users to be able to remove the anti-siphon device and continue to attach a garden hose to it. YOU WILL NOT FIND AN ADAPTER to hook your hose to that valve. You will need to replace the valve.

Comment: I agree it stinks but jimmy is correct, you may be able to contact the MFG but I’m my experience a valve replacement is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I established the spigot is ABP (Arrowhead), did some more digging and found this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNqqryd6rHs&t=101s
bought that BrassCraft piece from HomeDepot, 
https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-in-20-Fine-Thread-x-3-4-in-Hose-Thread-Brass-Garden-Hose-Vacuum-Breaker-PS612X/204618267
and it fit nicely. (The spigot seems like it's leaking around the knob-shaft, so I suspect the whole thing's going to need replacing anyway.)

Comment: After looking at the photos i was going to suggest that you replace the whole hose bib.