# Garden Hose Fit Issue

Tags: hose, spigot

Just moved into a new home and cant find the right garden hose + adapter combination to connect to my water spigot. I seem to have a very similar issue as to the question posed in:

[Can't find a garden hose that fits](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110913/cant-find-a-garden-hose-that-fits)

This is what my outdoor spigot looks like.

[image][image]

Based on the recommendation from the other post, I purchased a "Homewerks Worldwide VACBFPZ4B Vacuum Breaker Hose Bib Backflow Preventer, 3/4 Inch, Brass Finish" from Amazon but that doesnt fit on the spigot.

[image]

any help in figuring out the correct adapter/piece for this so I can attach a garden hose would be appreciated.

Comment: The second comment on that linked question seems to be right.  You have an adapter or part of an adapter left on the faucet.  Once it is removed(good cleaning and tapping) you should be able to fit a garden hose on it.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial step in preparing the hose bibb (what you've called a "spigot") for a garden hose is to *remove the additional piece*, exactly as described in the [other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110913/cant-find-a-garden-hose-that-fits). The side view from that other question shows the additional piece:

[image]

The additional piece has a knurled exterior ring and exposed fine threads. This additional piece must be removed from the hose bibb before a hose can be added.

The photo you've included in your question shows the additional piece still in place. Holding the body of the hose bibb with one wrench, use a second pipe wrench to unscrew the additional piece. That will expose the standard, hose-size threads on the hose bibb.